# Can't render spot light with texture

Tags: rendering, texturing

I am trying to render a scene with a spot light and a texture attached to it. Rendering works fine with the Blender renderer. With either cycles or Mitsuba renderers the texture is not rendered.
[image]
Any ideas?

Thanks

-Arrigo

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set up a new cycles material for the spotlight. Blender Internal and Cycles use different shaders/materials for objects and lamps.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with this kind of nodes configuration for the spot lamp :

[image]

The important point for the projection is too choose "normal" in the texture coordinate node.