# Avoid distortions when creating projector effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, light

Im my scene, a point light is right above a table, and the light is textured to mimic a projector.
[image: Projector]
However, the projection is slightly distorted. Is there a way to solve this problem?
[image: Node tree]
The script node is only for changing the colour of the texture, it does not affect how the texture is mapped.

Comment: For the light position play with the mapping "location" values.
For the fireflies, check here: [www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/)

Comment: As I see now, I don't think I have understood right the issue - the problem is the light position or the texture mapping of the square mesh?

Answer (score 8):

Wanted to add an answer here since this comes up first in google:

Between your Texture Coordinate node and your Mapping node, you should divide the X and Y parts of the normal vector by the Z part, and set the Z part to 1.

[image]

This was apparently reported as a bug in 2010, deemed expected behavior, and never fixed:

https://developer.blender.org/T22272

so thanks to the original reporter for the analysis and the solution.