# Light source direction/position as Texture Coordinate

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

is there any way to use a light source' position/direction as a control for "Texture Coordinate" in the node editor? (in cycles)

So that when I move the light source around it adjusts the coordinates of the texture.

Comment: Texture Coordinates node has Object coordinates and a field where you can specify which object to use for mapping, so try pointing the node to the light source and using Object socket output

Comment: On the receiving object you can add a [UVproject modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html) and use a lamp (or any other object, even an empty) to project an image on the texture. Or if you are looking for a way to use the lamp as a video projector see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/correct-vector-input-to-map-texture-light-in-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62665/avoid-distortions-when-creating-projector-effect