# Remove Spot Light Texture Distortion

Tags: light

I'm currently trying to create a Ending Credits scene within a isometric cube that looks like a movie projector.

My current scene setup is this: [image]

But the projection is with some distortions when it comes to the top of the cube, how can I project this spot light without distortion?

[image]

Comment: related:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62665/avoid-distortions-when-creating-projector-effect

Comment: already tried but with no success, the distortion still occurs whether if the output of "Texture Coordinate" is reflection or normal. https://image.ibb.co/mjTiec/apague.jpg