# How can I change the perspective of an image with nodes?

Tags: shaders

I'm making a class scene, and I've made a simple projector that displays an image on a whiteboard, everything works just fine, but the image has the perspective that is normally cancelled to look squared in real life projectors.
So is there a way to cancel out that warping **with** nodes? I'd prefer not to manually correct the images somewhere else.

[image: The problem in question]

If it wasn't clear, I'm trying to scale the top part up horizontally.

[image: My node setup]

This is the node setup is very simple, just an image connected to the emission color with some mapping stuff to remove the pincushion effect.

Comment: It depends on your set up.. [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173561/35559) 
 may work.. could you show us your light-nodes?

Comment: Yes, that absolutely answers my question, thanks!

Comment: You might want to consider mapping the image directly to the screen with an emission shader, that way you don't need to worry about keystoning. Most effects in 3D are just about how to fake things anyway.