# How to get rid of Pincushion Distortion of Projector?

Tags: node-editor, lighting, texture-coordinates

According to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adahnQCqmw0) the solution to the distortion is to use the node setup in screenshot 2. However, the nodes completely mess up the image. Is there any other solution to get the edges straight?

[image: Pincustion Distortion]

[image: Solution which doesn't work]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62665/78972

Answer (score 0):

The problem only occurs with spotlights. It works better with an area light. no distortion whatsoever.

[image: Area light Projector]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. it turns out all you have to do is ensure you're using a *Vector Math* node, as opposed to a *Math* node. That's why your screenshot has a *Clamp* option (which the video does not).