# Spotlight Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, light, texture-coordinates

I'm quite new to blender cycles and wanted to create a game using Armory3D in blender 2.79 which supports cycles. I started out by creating a character and wanted to add a flashlight that has some sort of 'flashlight texture'. When I looked it up in the internet and tried improving my knowledge I still couldn't find anything to help my and I ended up with a spotlight looking like this:
[image]

Is there any known way how I can make it look right?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct vector input to map texture light in Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/correct-vector-input-to-map-texture-light-in-cycles)

Comment: I didn’t understand any of the things you’ve just said

Comment: He's suggesting that the texture is not mapped right because of the vector coordinates. Its offset in x and y axis.