# Replicate the light coming from a projector

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, volumetrics

Trying to create projection light to put on a scene like this 1
[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge.*</sup>

Example of the light I want to create.

[image]

How would I do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure you used the [search function](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cycles%20projector) and found how to make a [projector spot lamp](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91192/30849) in cycles.

With this node setup you only need to add a cube with a [Volume Scatter](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/shaders/volume_scatter.html) to create the volumetric lighting.

[image]

- Use a highly saturated image.
- Use a high contrast image.
- If your image is neither, increase saturation and contrast with material nodes.
- Use a low lamp size (0.0), otherwise your image will be blurry.
- Use a strong lamp emission intensity (my value: 7000).
- Use a small density of the volume scatter material.
- Only encase the necessary areas with the volume scatter node to speed up rendering .