# How can i apply gobos to a spotlight to make it look like a real life moving head light?

Tags: light, lighting, eevee-render-engine, masking

as you may know most moving head lights used on live stages and dj shows have a gobo feature which allow the light to be restrained on some parts of the spot, as if a cookie cutter was placed in front of the light source, this results in various shapes[image: gobos].
How can i recreate this effect in blender on a light ?(i'm using 2.8 and Eevee)
i already have some black and white gobo textures ready if it can help (see picture below)

[image]

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Please try the solutions of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57013/30849), [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/64147/30849) or [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/127028/30849).

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me (for the same exact purpose) was to use either geometry (as @RBlong2us suggested - with the wanted shape made firstly as a vector image and then extruded in Blnder) or even simpler (as is in my example) by using a plane and put it in front of my spotlight (as a real gobo would be) with an alpha texture. In order to make this working you should take care of the blend Mode and Shadow Mode of the plane's material. You may take a look on the image below.

[image]

Comment: Excellent idea, @cnisidis!  My complements!  We both had a similar idea, but yours is definitely more efficient!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way!  Create a mesh that will act like a cardboard cutout which you put right in front of the spot light.  Just make the cardboard cutout design whatever you want it.  If you want text, then create a font using the font tool, convert it into a mesh, and use the Boolean knife tool.
In order to make the cutout follow the spotlight, simply parent it to the spotlight.
Good luck!

P.S.  I'd suggest using atmospheric lighting.

Comment: i'll try this thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spotlight to project Textures. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/64162/47253

Volumetrics can help you acheve the beams. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67136/47253

Also spotlights can create fake beams called "halo". [How do I properly set up a spotlight cone?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6298/how-do-i-properly-set-up-a-spotlight-cone?rq=1)